# knockout - update UI (filter data) based on select/dropdown choice?

Tags: select, knockout.js, filtering, knockout-mapping-plugin

How can I update this UI based on the selection made in the select/dropdowns?

For example, if I select a member name from the select/dropdown, I want the table to update/filter to only show those member rows (member names are in far right column) AND their corresponding date header (the gray background).

If I select a provider name from the select/dropdown), I want the table to update/filter to only show those provider rows (provider names in left column) AND their corresponding date header (the gray background).

I'm using the KO mapping plugin.  The dummy data is hard coded and would eventually be returned via ajax.

Here's a fiddle of all the code (it's all just inlined in the HTML pane).  You could copy/paste this and run it locally if you wanted, as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/qBGTh/

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a *computed* value at *eob* level returning the filtered array. To add this computed value during the *mapping* process, you must customize the *eob* object creation using a *create* callback in the mapping options parameter (see [mapping doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html))

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/hA5Vj/3/) to see it in action.

Also don't forget to add 2 more observables to capture current values for the 2 *select* elements. The computed value will depend on those 2 observables.

> Note: the provided fiddle will not run on IE as github where is located the
>   *mapping* javascript does not return the *content-type* header required by IE.

Comment: **Awesome**, digging into this now....How can I exclude the gray row headers if they don't have any children?  For example, if you filter by member George Washington you'll see a swath of gray dates that don't have any children/data.

Comment: Wow, I see you can break this out and link this all up on jsfiddle as well.  I could swear it wouldn't let me link to raw.github for ko.mapping just a couple weeks ago.  Is there a trick I'm missing?  I tried doing it just like you apparently did, linking up via the manage resources panel on the far left.

Comment: just adding another _computed_ function (eobsFiltered) one level higher (at the _viewModel_ object) and checking that the eobsClaim array contains the selected elements.

Comment: IE blocks links coming from github as the content-type header is missing. Probably this is the cause. Try with another browser. I'm using chrome.

Comment: I was using Firefox and it didn't seem to fly, though I'm in FF now and your fiddle works.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your first comment above.  I've an updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hA5Vj/5/ look for the "addition" comment at the bottom of the JS pane.  Also, can you check the comments under the EobModel function to see if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Well, I finally got it, but I took a different approach.  I took a break, came back, thought about it a bit more and just put a visible: eobClaimsFiltered().length on the td of the gray row headers.

Comment: Here the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/dvmtP/) with filtered headers.

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing that versus the visible: eobClaimsFiltered().length I put on the td of the gray row headers?  That seems to work fine.